# What is the difference between sp_start_job and sp_cdc_start_job?

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2012

What is the difference between `sp_start_job` and `sp_cdc_start_job`? When do you use one over other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sp_start_job -> Instructs SQL Server Agent to execute a job immediately.

sp_cdc_start_job -> Starts a change data capture cleanup or capture job for the current database.

You'll need to look up on Capture Jobs and Cleanup Jobs